# 'Autodiscover service couldn't be located': Exchange

Tags: exchange-server-2007

```
ExchangeService Service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("abc", "123456", "mydomain.net");
Service.TraceEnabled = true;
Service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
Service.EnableScpLookup = false;
Service.AutodiscoverUrl("abc@mydomain.net");
Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(Service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
Console.WriteLine("The folder name is " + inbox.DisplayName.ToString());
```

I am trying to login by exchange by it keep error of 'Autodiscover service couldn't be located'. Username-Password are fine.